# Is there any online spreadsheet app with VBA support?

Tags: webapp-rec

I know that a lot of them support importing spreadsheets from Microsoft Excel but what if the file contains VB code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Zoho sheet](http://sheet.zoho.com/): http://sheet.zoho.com/vbaobjectexplorer.do and http://vbmacros.wiki.zoho.com/
I haven't experimented with it but they claim some VBA support. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any that allow you to import the VB code. Google Docs Spreadsheets has added the ability to create scripts. Take a look at [this article](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/expense_report_approval.html). Also [this page has many more articles on getting started](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-script).